# Unable to inherit BaseUser class with FOSUserBundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I am doing a small FOSUserBundle test and due to some requirements I am using the 1.3 version.

Following the tutorial on the bundle's page, I have created my own User entity inheriting from FOSUserBundle's BaseUser.

However, when I am trying to update the schema, the only field created is the id I've specified in my own class and none of the BaseUser superclass fields are created into the table.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? My code is public at (https://github.com/andrei-dascalu/symfony-test)

Strangely if I simply switch to 2.0@dev then everything is magically created!

Thanks!

Comment: So you did this?  php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Answer (score 0):

If you use FOSUserBundle 1.3.5, please read the documentation in the 1.3.x branch, not the master branch. I'm quite sure you are extending the FOS\UserBundle\Model\User in your own user class, while you must extend FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User in 1.3.x

**To be clear:**

*symfony-test/src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php LINE 5*

> use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

**Switch to**

> use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

**And don't forget to add this to your Entity:**

```
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}
```

Comment: and after shows an error that we forget to use ...\Model\

Comment: This is an old topic. There is a new version (2.x). You need to use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;